# "Execution was interrupted" error when tokenising by CreateML

Tags: swift, swift-playground, coreml, createml

I created a simple macOS playground to make coreML text classifier as follows:

```
import Cocoa
import CreateML

let url = URL(string: "https://github.com/novinfard/profiler-sentiment-analysis/raw/master/ml-model/essays.csv")
let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: url!)
let (trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)
let sentimentClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: trainingData,
                                               textColumn: "TEXT",
                                               labelColumn: "cEXT")
// Training accuracy as a percentage
let trainingAccuracy = (1.0 - sentimentClassifier.trainingMetrics.classificationError) * 100

// Validation accuracy as a percentage
let validationAccuracy = (1.0 - sentimentClassifier.validationMetrics.classificationError) * 100

print("training accuracy -> \(trainingAccuracy) validation accuracy ->\(validationAccuracy)")
```

But I got "Execution was interrupted" error.

Here is the log during the process:

```
Parsing completed. Parsed 100 lines in 0.078347 secs.
Finished parsing file https://github.com/novinfard/profiler-sentiment-analysis/raw/master/ml-model/essays.csv
Parsing completed. Parsed 2467 lines in 0.113062 secs.
Automatically generating validation set from 5% of the data.
Tokenizing data and extracting features
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Was there an error message?

Comment: yes, just "Execution was interrupted"

Comment: It looks like a bug in Create ML. When you run this code from lldb it definitely shows a crash deep inside Create ML. I suggest filing a bug report with Apple. You could also try using a simpler / smaller dataset to see if that makes a difference.